# How to show two integers are coprime in a linear combination?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime if and only if 1 is expressible as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Using that fact, show that any two consecutive integers are relatively prime.

Well the linear combination is $1=ax+by$. But how do I show $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. I know relatively prime means that both numbers don't have any common divisors between the two except one. I've expressed the linear combination, but how does one show $a$ and $b$ are coprimes.

Comment: Because any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $1$.

Comment: Not sure what $x,y$ are in your expression.  The desired linear combination is just $b-a=1$ (assuming that $b$ is the larger).

Comment: $x,y$ are integers while $a,b$ is a linear combination and $1$ is their greatest divisors. My problem is how do I show that $a,b$ are coprimes.

Comment: @lulu that is incorrect.  An arbitrary linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is of the form $ax+by$ where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary integers.  Are you suggesting that because $3$ and $7$ are coprime that $7-3=1$?  It is saying that $a$ and $b$ are coprime iff there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz  The OP specifies that the integers $a,b$ are consecutive.

Comment: After having proven the more general statement about not necessarily consecutive integers first @lulu.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Agreed.  I was only focussed on the second part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose they're not relatively prime, with common factor $d > 1$. Then as $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $b$, you necessarily have that $d$ divides the right hand side $ax + by$, and thus $d$ divides $1$.

This shows that if $ax + by = 1$, then $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: So what your saying is if $d$ divides $a$ and $d$ divides $b$, $d$ also divides $1$ and because $d$ can divide $1$, that means $a$ and $b$ must be coprime?

Comment: Explicitly, if $d|a$ and $d|b$ AND $ax + by = 1$, then since $d|a$ we have $a = du$, and since $d|b$ we have $b = dv$, for some integers $u,v$. Thus $1 = ax + by = (du)x + (dv)y = d(ux + vy)$. So any common divisor of $a,b$ when $ax + by = 1$ divides $1$. The (integer) divisors of $1$ are severely limited-only $1$ and $-1$ qualify, and of these two, $1$ is clearly the greatest.